# Is my default.xml in the correct location?

Tags: magento2, xml

I am trying to remove the footer links on my theme. I am using the Luma theme as a parent theme.

I added this code-

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
```

To my default.xml file. I then copied that file to

/files/magento2/project-community-edition/app/design/frontend/Magento/ThemeName/layout

I have checked and made sure my theme is physical and not virtual.

I have purged every cache multiple times but still no luck. I am trying this on Magento 2.1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
/files/magento2/project-community-edition/app/design/frontend/Magento/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/layout
```

Comment: That worked! Nothing I looked at told me to create a different folder for it. Do you know where any documentation is that shows when I need to do that? Or to learn more about it?

Comment: Sound like my experience. I actually had to reference I theme I built, I honestly have no idea when or how I figured that out though. Most of the theming stuff I've done does involved overriding Magento_Theme or the relevant module, but there may be a way to do it like you originally tried. I just don't know :-